# How make a Grid Type using Javascript and json Data

Tags: javascript

I need to build something similar this using Div not table, using Javascript. The Data is in Json format. I m not sure how build a header: Id,Name, Age

```
 Id       Name      Age
 1        Sam       21
 2        tim       20
 3        min       25
```

and this is my javascript/TypeScript Code:

```js
function greet() {

  let data = '[{"data": [{"id": "1","name": "Sam","age": "32"}, {"id": "2","name": "tom","age": "22"}, {"id": "3","name": "mina","age": "25"}]}]';
  let mydata = JSON.parse(data);
  var header = document.getElementById("header");



  for (var i = 0; i < mydata[0].data.length; i++) {
    var it = mydata[0].data[i];


    AddRecord(it, i);

  }
}

function AddRecord(record, n) {
  var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  newdiv.innerHTML = "<div style=''>" + record.id + "</div>" + "<div>" + record.name + "</div>" + "<div>" + record.age + "</div>";
  var detail = document.getElementById("detail");
  detail.appendChild(newdiv);
  console.log(detail);
}

greet()
```

```html
<div id="detail"></div>
```

Comment: Check out DataTables https://www.datatables.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AddRecord` do a test on `n`, when its `0` (the first row) insert a header row first

Also, try using [flex box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) to make your divs display like a table

```js
function greet() {

  let data = '[{"data": [{"id": "1","name": "Sam","age": "32"}, {"id": "2","name": "tom","age": "22"}, {"id": "3","name": "mina","age": "25"}]}]';
  let mydata = JSON.parse(data);
  var header = document.getElementById("header");



  for (var i = 0; i < mydata[0].data.length; i++) {
    var it = mydata[0].data[i];

    AddRecord(it, i);

  }
}

function AddRecord(record, n) {

  var detail = document.getElementById("detail");

  if( n == 0 ){
      var header = document.createElement("div");
      header.innerHTML = '<div>ID</div><div>Name</div><div>Age</div>'
      detail.appendChild(header);
  }

  var newdiv = document.createElement("div");
  newdiv.innerHTML = "<div style=''>" + record.id + "</div>" + "<div>" + record.name + "</div>" + "<div>" + record.age + "</div>";
  detail.appendChild(newdiv);
}

greet()
```

```css
#detail {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#detail > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

#detail > div > div {
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  flex-basis: 33%
}
```

```html
<div id="detail"></div>
```